# Update CLOB Column to NULL

Tags: oracle

I need to update an oracle clob column value to `null`.  I tried to below but that didn't work.  Any ideas?

```
update table_name 
   set CONTENT_TEMPLATE=empty_clob() 
 where table_key=12345;


Name                 Null     Type          
-------------------- -------- ------------- 
TEST_KEY            NOT NULL NUMBER(10)    
TEST_ID             NOT NULL VARCHAR2(100) 
TEST_TYPE           NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)  
TEMPLATE_ID                   VARCHAR2(100) 
ROUTE                         VARCHAR2(100) 
MEDIUM                        VARCHAR2(100) 
BEGIN_EFFECTIVE_DATE NOT NULL DATE          
END_EFFECTIVE_DATE   NOT NULL DATE          
CUSTOMER_ID          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)  
VAR_ID               NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)  
CREATION_DATE        NOT NULL DATE          
LAST_UPDATED_DATE    NOT NULL DATE          
LAST_UPDATED_BY      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)  
CONTENT_TEMPLATE              CLOB          
SUBJECT_TEMPLATE              CLOB          
UNIT_TYPE                     VARCHAR2(30)  
OVERLOADED_ALERT_KEY          NUMBER(10)    
ALERT_TYPE_ALIAS              VARCHAR2(100)
```

Comment: For the record `empty_clob()` is not `NULL`.

Comment: Is there an update trigger on the table?

Answer (score 2):

```
update table_name 
   set column_name = null 
 where table_key=12345;
```

`NULL` - Absense of data

`empty_clob()` - `CLOB` is initialized and empty, not same as `NULL`.

If you still get `ORA-01407` with this column then that means there is a `NOT NULL` constraint on the column which is of `CLOB` datatype.

**UPDATE:**

Since the `CLOB` column is not `NOT NULL` setting it to `CONTENT_TEMPLATE = NULL` should work. `CONTENT_TEMPLATE = empty_clob()` will also work, but bear in mind that it is not same as `NULL`.

Comment: I can't do that for this clob column, I get SQL Error: ORA-01407: cannot update ("user"."table"."column") to NULL
01407. 00000 -  "cannot update (%s) to NULL"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: That is because there is a `NOT NULL` constraint on the column. Not because it is a `BLOB`. Do a `desc` on the table and you will see.

Comment: when I run select * from table where column IS NULL; I get results

Comment: Please do a `desc table_name` and post the output to your question.

Comment: added. CONTENT_TEMPLATE is the column in question.  I looks like the web app that uses this table doesn't insert any value for this column so it gets defaulted to null.  I don't think there is a way to update an existing data row.

Comment: In oracle, yes there is a way to update a data row using `UPDATE` whether the `UPDATE` statement is valid or not is entirely different case.

Comment: It's also possible the NOT NULL constraint was added to the table after there already were NULL entries in it, with the NOVALIDATE clause. What did you get when you did a `desc` on the table?

Comment: Desc results are in my original question